# Configuration of Allure report for selenium with C#, specflow tests

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, specflow, nunit-3.0

I'm using Selenium with C#, specflow and NUnit 3 to create my automated tests. Now I am looking for reporting tool like Allure. Can anyone guide me, how to configure Allure report please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check https://www.nuget.org/packages/Specflow.Allure/

Make sure you're using NUnit 3 version which supports **TextFixtureSetUp/TextFixtureTearDown** (like 3.2), because SpecFlow uses old NUnit and this attributes became deprecated in newer NUnit versions.

**Specflow.Allure** currently supports SpecFlow 2.1 and will support 2.2 as soon as my PR will be approved.